# Graph Creator Online

Tags: graphing-functions, math-software

Looking for a website preferable, or a download which will allow me to plot graphs in parameter space not just for x and y.

E.g I want to plot a graph against alpha and beta. I know I could just substitute x and y in, but the axis need to be labeled alpha and beta.

Thanks